# Can't make media queries work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm building a responsive wordpress theme and trying to set up size changing font, depending on screen width. Somebody suggested jquery, but i also decided to try css media queries. Font size still doesn't change and entire text slides under header background.

Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr4/

Code looks like this

```
<div class="container-full" id="spbg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5"><div class="visible-md visible-lg" id="gr"></div>
        <div class="visible-sm visible-xs" id="grsm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg sptxt" id="sptxt">
            <?php
                $post_id = 127;
                $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
                echo $queried_post->post_content;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#spbg {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white !important;
  background-image: url(http://soloveich.com/pr4/wp-content/themes/blain/images/spbg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#sptxt {
  padding-right:20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 70px;
}
#gr {
  width: 417px;
  height: 283px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  background-image: url(http://soloveich.com/pr4/wp-content/themes/blain/images/gr.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#splmd {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .sptxt {
      font-size:10px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1124px) {
  .sptxt {
    font-size:29px;
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can't answer my question because of very little reputation, so commenting here. dumb me :(
it was sliding because of large columns. Made them small and everything worked perfectly. Damn, i feel dumb...

Answer (score 0):

You're using `.sptxt` instead of `#sptxt`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #sptxt {
font-size:10px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1124px) {
    #sptxt {
font-size:29px;
}
}
```

Comment: I did that. Didn't work. I tried setting up #sptxt default font size 10px and then @media screen and (min-width: 1124px) {
        #sptxt {
    font-size:29px;
    }
} didn't work as well

Comment: try #spbg #sptxt { font-size:

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ID (`#sptxt`) in the media query not class (`.sptxt`)

```
#sptxt {
font-size:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like anything is wrong from my browser (I'm on the latest Chrome on Windows 8.1). I'd post a picture, but I don't have the reputation for that yet.

And to others who are saying that he needs to be using the ID and not the class - why? He includes the class sptxt as well as the ID, so either one should work just fine.

Comment: My bad. I didn't post it clearly. As soon as i get width around 1024 and less, text slides down without because, initially default font size was 29, and it was too large to stay in place.

Comment: Ah. Well in that case, the problem seems to be that the text is white-on-white, and once you hit 991 pixels, you're actually using a _different_ piece of HTML to show the _same_ content (I can't exactly see why that is, but there's probably a good reason that I'm just missing). EDIT: never mind, didn't see that you found it already :P

Answer (score 0):

It's working :- Because of white color the text disappers.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #sptxt {
font-size:10px;
color: #000;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1124px) {
    #sptxt {
font-size:29px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me .. try Firefox developer tools "Responsive Design View". It's taking its 10px font-size from #sptxt class from main.css line 69

tested on Chrome 30+ also